# Transition color

Tags: ios, animation, transition

I would like to change the color of my navigation bar, with animation.

I tried CATransition but I can't find how to change the color with that.

Is there a way to change the color with a fading or any other animation ?
 Like TransitionDrawable in Android.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UINavigationBar change Tint color with animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042283/uinavigationbar-change-tint-color-with-animation)

Comment: In iOS7 the color of the navigation bar changes **always** animated. If you simply set the color in code there is a smooth, maybe 0.5s animation.

Comment: I already read this post, but I didn't read the second post explaining it's not possible to animate the background color...

Comment: @MarcMosby Do you know how to slow this animation for like 1 more second ?

Comment: The solution was animating the barTinTColor and not the backgroundColor !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried some stuff and finally ended up with this solution. It doesn't need any extra layers, images or transition views and makes use of the built-in animation of the bar.

Therefore it does not hide any titles and bar buttons that you have placed on your navigation bar. If the nav bar is below a status bar, the status bar's color will also be changed.

This is tested with iOS7, both for simulator as well as real device (iPad)

**The code:**

Right below your imports do

```
#define STEP_DURATION 0.01
```

You can play with this value for a smoother animation

This is the method that you want to call

```
[self animateNavigationBarFromColor:[UIColor greenColor] toColor:[UIColor blueColor] duration:2.5];
```

Parameters should be self-explaining (duration is in seconds).

And this is the actual code

```
- (void)animateNavigationBarFromColor:(UIColor *)fromColor toColor:(UIColor *)toColor duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    NSUInteger steps = duration / STEP_DURATION;

    CGFloat fromRed;
    CGFloat fromGreen;
    CGFloat fromBlue;
    CGFloat fromAlpha;

    [fromColor getRed:&fromRed green:&fromGreen blue:&fromBlue alpha:&fromAlpha];

    CGFloat toRed;
    CGFloat toGreen;
    CGFloat toBlue;
    CGFloat toAlpha;

    [toColor getRed:&toRed green:&toGreen blue:&toBlue alpha:&toAlpha];

    CGFloat diffRed = toRed - fromRed;
    CGFloat diffGreen = toGreen - fromGreen;
    CGFloat diffBlue = toBlue - fromBlue;
    CGFloat diffAlpha = toAlpha - fromAlpha;

    NSMutableArray *colorArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    [colorArray addObject:fromColor];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < steps - 1; ++i) {
        CGFloat red = fromRed + diffRed / steps * (i + 1);
        CGFloat green = fromGreen + diffGreen / steps * (i + 1);
        CGFloat blue = fromBlue + diffBlue / steps * (i + 1);
        CGFloat alpha = fromAlpha + diffAlpha / steps * (i + 1);

        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
        [colorArray addObject:color];
    }

    [colorArray addObject:toColor];

    [self animateWithArray:colorArray];
}

- (void)animateWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
    NSUInteger counter = 0;

    for (UIColor *color in array) {
        double delayInSeconds = STEP_DURATION * counter++;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [UIView animateWithDuration:STEP_DURATION animations:^{
                self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = color;
            }];
        });
    }
}
```

Drawback: It's not buttery smooth :(

Comment: Worderful, you gave my the answer I needed, barTinTColor can be animate ! But I simply need this code : self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f animations:^{
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];

Comment: Are you sure you don't need more? No matter what value you choose for duration, internally it will always be the same. That's why I made an animation loop.

Comment: UIView animateWithDuration make the animation for you, you don't need an animation loop. But I was using backgroundColor instead of barTinTColor that's my mystake.

Comment: Well I wrote the code, I know what animateWithDuration does ;) But did you try your code? Did the animation really take 5 seconds?

Comment: Of course it works, I already finish adding this feature to all my tabs with 5 differents color and it's working perfectly with the duration specified. Thanks again.

Comment: What device did you try that on? On my iPad (and iPad simulator) the duration didn't work, thats why I looped. Ofc I am happy for you if the much simpler version works, but would be interesting to know why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Ha you are right, it seems to work only on iOS 7, I got a crash in iOS 6.

Comment: iOS6 doesn't have the property `barTintColor`. You have to use `tintColor` there. You can test with `respondsToSelector:` if the property is available

Answer (score 0):

Is your `fading` just meaning changing alpha of navigationBar, See this code:

```
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)]) {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
} else {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}

self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:.2f animations:^{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 1.f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //
}];
```

Comment: I already tried that, but with the alpha the transition start with black, I want the transition starting with a color and finishing with another one. And my gold is to change only the background, not the entire navBar with the logo in it. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution that I will explain here.

As we can't change the backgroundColor attribut, we will need a trick to make an animation for changing  the navBar color with animation.

I choose to put above my navBar an identical subview with CATransition.

```
CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
UIImageView *logo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(77,3,163,38)];
[logo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_transparent.png"]];
[view addSubview:logo];

CATransition *myAnimationView = [CATransition animation];
[myAnimationView setDuration:1.5f];
[myAnimationView setType:kCATransitionReveal];
[myAnimationView setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[[view layer] addAnimation:myAnimationView forKey:kCATransitionReveal];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:view];
```

Comment: Find a better way animating the attribut barTinTColor of the navBar